# After add images to drawable "Cannot resolve symbol R" issue not going away after clean, rebuild etc

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't find a way to add images to drawable folder without getting "Cannot resolve symbol R" issue.

And once i get "Cannot resolve symbol R", I can't get rid of it by either clean, rebuild, sync, invalidate cache & restart solutions for the error. Only if i delete the files can I get the build to pass.

I am not sure what is wrong here.

Note: I am on Android Studio 2.1.1

Comment: @Ironman we're not sure if it is a duplicate yet, he said he tried everything.

Comment: Its not a duplicate issue guys.. all solutions on that thread are not resolving my issue

Comment: see my answer below@JamesMcP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are facing this issue because your drawable file name is either
>   having any **capital letter** or starting with a **number** or containing any **special character** like `@`,`*`,`$` etc. rename it the
>   error will be gone.

**You can use only small letters, underscore(_), numbers(not at beginning) & dot(.) in the name of drawable**

For example the name could be `ABC.png` then rename it to `abc.png` and it will work.

`1xYz.JPEG` then rename it to `_1xyz.jpeg`

`a@b.png` then rename it to `ab.png`

After that **clean and rebuild** & there you Go..!!

Comment: Thanks for helpful information. I found that my actual issue was that the image files i downloaded were corrupted and can't be opened in any image viewing apps. AS doesn't accept any image file that is corrupted either...

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and it was that I downloaded an "image.jpeg" extension from Internet  and directly changed the extension saving it like "image.png", but Android studio still recognized it like image.jpeg.

I realized that when using top menu Analyze-Inpect code.

Once the inspection is finished a new window called 'Inspection' appears and in the follow carpets appears next:

```
Android > Lint > Usability > Icons
Icon format does not match the file extension

     Misleading file extension; named .png but the file format is JPEG*
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the extension of the file must match the actual format of the image.

For example, you will get this error if you changed the extension of an image from bmp to png and added it to the project